# How do launcher apps uninstall apps in the background?

Tags: android, android-intent, uninstallation

### Background

I have a spare time app that one of its main features is to easily uninstall apps.

### The problem

I'm using a very basic API for uninstalling apps, which for the user seems like 2 steps: confirm uninstalling, and seeing some dialog showing the uninstall-process.

I've noticed that on some launcher apps (such as Nova launcher and Pixel Launcher), upon uninstall, they show only one step, of confirmation of uninstalling the chosen app.

Here's how it looks via my app and from the normal, built in screen of app-info. First you see this:

[image]

and then this:

[image]

However, on the launcher, you see just this:

[image]

And shortly after, the app is gone without you seeing anything in between.

### What I've found

Only way I know of uninstalling an app in the background, is by using root, but that's not what those apps do.

Here's what I use for the normal uninstall procedure:

```
public static Intent prepareUninstallAppIntent(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final String packageName) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.UNINSTALL_ALL_USERS", true);
    return null;
}
```

### The questions

1. How do the launcher apps only show the confirmation dialog alone, and perform the uninstall in the background?
2. Is it a new API? If so, from which version? And where can I read about it?

EDIT: this doesn't matter anymore. Got to see how it works.

---

I've now found, by looking at [**Lawnchair**](https://github.com/LawnchairLauncher/Lawnchair) launcher app code, that it's a bit similar to what I did:

```
public static boolean startUninstallActivity(
        final Launcher launcher, ItemInfo info, DropTargetResultCallback callback) {
    Pair<ComponentName, Integer> componentInfo = getAppInfoFlags(info);
    ComponentName cn = componentInfo.first;

    final boolean isUninstallable;
    if ((componentInfo.second & AppInfo.DOWNLOADED_FLAG) == 0) {
        // System applications cannot be installed. For now, show a toast explaining that.
        // We may give them the option of disabling apps this way.
        Toast.makeText(launcher, R.string.uninstall_system_app_text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isUninstallable = false;
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE,
                Uri.fromParts("package", cn.getPackageName(), cn.getClassName()))
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_USER, info.user);
        launcher.startActivity(intent);
        isUninstallable = true;
    }
    if (callback != null) {
        sendUninstallResult(
                launcher, isUninstallable, componentInfo.first, info.user, callback);
    }
    return isUninstallable;
}
```

It works there the same as on other launchers, so, to me it seemed they added the part of uninstalling for current user (got it using `android.os.Process.myUserHandle();` ) .

But I tried it anyway. Seems to work, so what I tried then is to remove more and more code till I got something that works without weird things.

Here's the minimal code:

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null));
```

and you just use startActivity, instead of startActivityForResult.

Yes. It's that short, and I wonder how long I've missed using this...

But now I got other questions:

1. What is the `cn.getClassName()` and the `Intent.EXTRA_USER` used for?
2. From which version of Android will this code uninstall the app in the background?
3. Is there any difference between ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE and ACTION_DELETE here?
4. I removed all flags and it still seem to do the same exact job, without a task that's in the history. Are they really needed?
5. Are there more ways to uninstall apps? Maybe in a batch?